# get all page IDs from wp_list_pages

Tags: wp-list-pages, id

I am looking for a way to output all page IDs from the following menu:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('depth=1&exclude='3,5,11')); ?>
```

Only top level pages needed, therefore the 'depth=1'.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_list_pages()` is for formatted markup. Use `get_pages()` and `wp_list_pluck()`:

```
$pages = get_pages(
    array (
        'parent'  => 0, // replaces 'depth' => 1,
        'exclude' => '3,5,11'
    )
);

$ids = wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' );
```

`$ids` holds an array of page IDs now.

Comment: +1 for showing me the `wp_list_pluck()` function. Nice. Never knew about that one before.

Comment: @GhostToast Yeah, that’s [really handy](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A73+wp_list_pluck). :)

Comment: When I run this code, I get child pages as well as top level ones. I've checked a couple of times to confirm. `get_pages` is returning all pages, not just the top level pages-- the `post_parent === 0` ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_parent' => 0,
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post__not_in' => array('3','5','11'),
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($qry->posts);
```

As you can see from the `var_dump`, `$qry->posts` is an array of `ID`s

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

```php
$pages = get_pages(
    array (
        'parent'   => 0, /* it gives only child of current page id */
        'child_of' => 'parent or page_ID' /* Return child of child for page id. */
    )
);
$ids = wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' );
```

Comment: The question was about the top level menu elements though. Is child_of correct? What would be the parent ID there?