# How can I list all page titles and IDs?

Tags: wp-list-pages

I currently use an sql query to produce a private page which lists all pages with their id. (It's a quick-check to help exclude some pages from search and site-map.)

For easier formatting, I'm wondering if there's a way to use list_pages (because of the formatting) to also show the ids?

Alternately, how do I list all pages and ids using Wp_Query or get_pages?

I've read 'get all page IDs from wp_list_pages' ([get all page IDs from wp_list_pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/get-all-page-ids-from-wp-list-pages)), but don't know what to add to get it to display results.

Answer (score 2):

To list all page title and id, you can try this code!

```
  $page_ids= get_all_page_ids();
    echo '<h3>My Page List :</h3>';
       foreach($page_ids as $id)
        {
            echo '<br />'.get_the_title($id).' ' .$id;
        }
```

[click here for more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_all_page_ids)

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen that page,, but didn't know how to modify the code.